# How do I make this let less water in

Tags: toilet, flushvlave

Our high cistern toilet flushes too violently and comes out of the toilet. I’ve seen a few posts suggesting I need to set the flush up to stop as much water coming in. However it’s too high for me to easily get in to work on it so I need to use my camera.

Attached a picture of the flush unit but the bit that looks like a screw where I can adjust is not actually a screw - it’s flatish.

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

[image: flush]

Comment: Usually the float is adjustable so you can adjust it to have less water in the tank.  The height of tank also adds to the force, so if the tank was lower should be less force, but that might be harder to fix.  The flush itself is usually just an open or close valve, but might have some adjustment on how open it gets.

Comment: They make ladders to solve the "too high to work on" problem. Use with care.

Comment: The ladders not the problem but the ceiling :)

Comment: The mechanism we're looking at in your pic is what adjusts the level of water in the tank, but doesn't have all that much effect on how fast it leaves the tank when you flush. You'll need to look at some way of limiting the flapper or whatever your tank has to control the outlet.

Comment: Is the bowl *specifically designed* for a high-cistern toilet? If you grab J. random toilet bowl, it's expecting to be attached to a tank in the normal location. That has a HUGE impact on water pressure - water pressure is 1 PSI per 2 feet, so you're tripling the water pressure. It's not a small thing.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get up there or have someone else get up there and turn that knob that stems into the blue float counterclockwise. The knob will not move up or down but it will lower the float and reduce the amount of water in the cistern.

There are also flappers out there that can be adjusted but we can't see the one you've got installed there.

Comment: And the adjustment won't take effect until the next fill/flush cycle (which should be obvious, but...)